# Git clone with ssh address failed

Tags: git

I want to clone a git repo from Github with the command

```
git clone git@github.com:rgov/Thunderbolt3Unblocker.git
```

but I get

```
Cloning into 'Thunderbolt3Unblocker'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com:rgov/Thunderbolt3Unblocker.git/': Port number ended with 'r'
```

It seem git interprets username "rgov" as port number?

The git version is 2.27.0

Comment: `git clone https://username:password@github.com/rgov/Thunderbolt3Unblocker.git`

Comment: What you’ve written normally works, but try `git clone ssh://git@github.com/rgov/Thunderbolt3Unblocker.git` to see if there’s an improved error message? Maybe your Git doesn’t support SSH?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `git config -l --show-origin | grep insteadof` as a code block.  Also you should not put passwords or other secrets in the URL.

Comment: Git downcases it when parsing it, and so when printing it with `git config -l`.  I checked, because I also write it `insteadOf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `git config --global -l` output for any insteadOf directive, like:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com".insteadOf git@github.com
```

That would explain why `git@github.com` whas replaced by https://github.com

Note that this directive is not well written: it should have been:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
                                          ^^^                        ^^^
```

That would at least gave you a valid HTTPs URL:

```
https://github.com/rgov/Thunderbolt3Unblocker.git
                 ^^^
```

But if you want to use SSH, delete that `insteadOf` directive from your global git configuration.

```
git config --global --unset-all url."https:github.com".insteadof
```